# Corrupt xlsx file created by xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have the following code to create an .xlsx file with `xlsxwriter`:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_path)
workbook.encoding='utf-8'
df_report = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'other', 'days', 'id', 'type',
        'call_type', 'role', 'breach'])
df_report = pd.concat([df_report, rpt1[rpt1['name'] == clientName]])
df_report.sort_values(by = ['breach'], inplace = True, ascending = False)
df_report = df_report[['other', 'days', 'id', 'role','breach']]
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('RPT_001_Q')
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'logo.png', {'x_scale': 0.25, 'y_scale': 0.25})

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 2,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'white'})
worksheet.merge_range('A1:C5', '', merge_format)
merge_format.set_border_color('green')
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
worksheet.write('A6', 'Report Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B6', self.date, bold)
worksheet.write('A7', 'Report Name:', bold)
worksheet.write('B7', 'RPT_001_Q ', bold)
worksheet.write('A8', 'Begin Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B8', start, bold)
worksheet.write('A9', 'End Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B9', end, bold)
worksheet.write('A10', 'Entity:', bold)
worksheet.write('B10', client, bold)
worksheet.write('A11', 'Type:', bold)
worksheet.write('B11', 'Type A', bold)
worksheet.write('A12', 'Call Type:', bold)
worksheet.write('B12', 'Type D', bold)
if len(df_report) == 0:
    worksheet.write('A13', 'No Data found for this Report in the time constraint given', bold)
else:
    table = 'A13:E' + str(len(df_report) + 13)
    data = df_report.values.tolist()
    worksheet.add_table(table, {'data' : data, 'style': 'Table Style Medium 1', 'columns' : [ 

                                                {'header' : 'other'}, 
                                                {'header' : 'days'},
                                                {'header' : 'id'}, 
                                                {'header' : 'role'}, 
                                                {'header':'breach'},]})
workbook.close()
```

The output file gives this error upon opening in Excel:

```
Excel cannot open the file 'rpt.xlsx' because the file format or file 
extention is not valid
```

When trying to read the excel file back into python (using `pandas.read_excel()`), I receive an error stating `File size 0 bytes`

I cannot seem to figure out a way to fix this, and have spend a good number of days trying to solve it. **ANY** help would be greatly appreciated!

---------------------------**EDIT**-----------------------------------------

I tried removing the `insert_image()` and `add_table()` statements, but found the worksheet was still corrupt.

Comment: what excel version are you using? and can python read that Excel file when you are done writing it?

Comment: Excel version 1803 and xlsxwriter 1.05.
And I havent attempted to read the file as I dont know how to read a .xlsx file

Comment: `pd.read_excel('PATH_HERE')` to read. other options also exist. Try figuring that out as well :)

Comment: "File size is 0 bytes"

Comment: `workbook.close()` ? Isn't that necessary?

Comment: At a guess I would start by excluding the add_table() from the code and seeing it that fixes the issue. If it does then debug the add_table() code.

Answer (score 2):

It saves time for you, and the people answering, if you can add a fully working program.

I've modified your example to include some sample data and turned some of the variable like `self.date` into strings:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

file_path = 'test.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_path)

data_list = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15]
df_report = pd.DataFrame({'other': data_list,
                          'days': data_list,
                          'id': data_list,
                          'role': data_list,
                          'breach': data_list})

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('RPT_001_Q')
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'logo.png', {'x_scale': 0.9, 'y_scale': 0.9})

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 2,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'white'})

worksheet.merge_range('A1:C5', '', merge_format)
merge_format.set_border_color('green')
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

worksheet.write('A6', 'Report Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B6', 'self.date', bold)
worksheet.write('A7', 'Report Name:', bold)
worksheet.write('B7', 'RPT_001_Q ', bold)
worksheet.write('A8', 'Begin Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B8', 'start', bold)
worksheet.write('A9', 'End Date:', bold)
worksheet.write('B9', 'end', bold)
worksheet.write('A10', 'Entity:', bold)
worksheet.write('B10', 'client', bold)
worksheet.write('A11', 'Type:', bold)
worksheet.write('B11', 'Type A', bold)
worksheet.write('A12', 'Call Type:', bold)
worksheet.write('B12', 'Type D', bold)

if len(df_report) == 0:
    worksheet.write('A13', 'No Data found for this Report in the time constraint given', bold)
else:
    table = 'A13:E' + str(len(df_report) + 13)
    data = df_report.values.tolist()
    worksheet.add_table(table, {'data' : data, 'style': 'Table Style Medium 1', 'columns' : [

                                                {'header' : 'other'},
                                                {'header' : 'days'},
                                                {'header' : 'id'},
                                                {'header' : 'role'},
                                                {'header':'breach'},]})
workbook.close()
```

The output file isn't corrupted, see below, so is there some part of the program that you left out that might be having an effect?

[image]